# How to generate an XSD file for below xml with some constrains?

Tags: xsd

I wanted to generate an XSD file for below xml with some constraints:

a) There should be more than one job elements in Cluster element.

b) In Job element,

i) `<name>` and `<id>` elements are mandatory and required to appear only one.

ii) `</parentjobid>` element can be present or absent and can appear more than one.

iii) `<description>` can be present or absent

iv) Elements can be in any order in Job element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Cluster name="abc" id="101" >
<job>   
    <name>ansys</name>
    <id>1001</id>
    <parentjobid>12</parentjobid>
    <description>This is thermal analysis</description>
</job>
<job>   
    <name>cfx</name>
    <id>1002</id>
    <parentjobid>122</parentjobid>
    <parentjobid>121</parentjobid>
</job>
</Cluster>
```

Below is an XSD I have created, but it does not obey the above rules. 
Kindly share me, how does this xsd can be written better way

## xsd:

```
<xs:element name="job">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" >        
        <xs:element ref="name" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element ref="jobid" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element ref="description" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element ref="parentjobid" maxOccurs="32" minOccurs="0" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType> 
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"  />  
  <xs:element name="jobid"  >
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger"   >
        <xs:minInclusive value="1"></xs:minInclusive>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="65536"></xs:maxInclusive>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>  
  <xs:element name="parentjobid" >
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger" >        
        <xs:minInclusive value="1"></xs:minInclusive>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="65536"></xs:maxInclusive>               
      </xs:restriction>      
    </xs:simpleType> 
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements *iv) Elements **can be in any order** in Job element.* and *ii)  element can be present or absent **and can appear more than one**.* are mutually exclusive.

See my [answer on a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089730/is-it-possible-to-restrict-elements-to-a-max-occur-in-a-choice-block/5123523#5123523) and some alternatives.

Comment: Thanks a lot Filburt for your reply. I got this issue now. I guess either, I have to use XML Schema1.1 or any other parser to accomplish this validation. My choice element have >15 element, So applying combination would be bad choice here.