# How to mix indicators..?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am having A and B, both are group ref.
I want to use in any order but A multiple times B only once.

```
<xs:___>
<group ref="A"/>
<group ref="B"/>
</xs:___>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible - see [alternatives in my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089730/is-it-possible-to-restrict-elements-to-a-max-occur-in-a-choice-block/5123523#5123523).